# With this approximation of $\pi$, will this value converge?

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

For some positive integer $n$, define $I_n$ as
\begin{align}
I_n&=\int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \pi^x\ln^n\pi \: dx \\
\end{align}
this integral has the following form
\begin{align*}
I_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( \pi p_k(\ln\pi) - k! ) \tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $a_0,a_1,...,a_n$ are integers and $p_0(\ln\pi),p_1(\ln\pi),...,p_n(\ln\pi)$ are polynomials with degree $0$, $1$,...,$n$ respectively, evaluated at $\ln\pi$.

This integral is positive and will always converge, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}I_n=0$. Notice that $\pi$ is present in expression $(1)$. (I'm not talking about $\pi$ inside the $\ln$ but rather the factor the multiplies $p_k$). What will happen if we change this $\pi$ to an approximation of it? Consider the expression,
\begin{align*}
J_n&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( S_n p_k(\ln\pi) - k! )
\end{align*}
where $S_n$ is a truncated series such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\pi$. For example, consider the truncated BBP formula
\begin{align*}
S_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{f(n)}\left( \frac{4}{16^k(8k+1)}
-   \frac{2}{16^k(8k+4)}
-   \frac{1}{16^k(8k+5)}
-   \frac{1}{16^k(8k+6)}\right)
\end{align*}
where $f(n)$ is some function in $n$ such that the following must be true
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{16^{f(n)}e^{8f(n)}}{n!}=0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

I noticed that if we choose a bad $f(n)$ such as $f(n)=n$, our $S_n$ will approximate $\pi$ very slowly, and $J_n$ will diverge to infinity or negative infinity as $n$ grows larger. For example, with $f(100)=100$ we must only iterate the BBP formula $100$ times giving a bad approximation to $\pi$ which results in  the large difference between $I_{100}=7.7472...\cdot  10^{-241}$ and $J_{100}=-3.2990\cdot 10^{84}$.

However, if we choose $f(n)=\lfloor n(\ln n)^{0.99}\rfloor$ the limit $(2)$ will be true (I used SageMath to evaluate this), and it gives a much better approximation. For example, now $f(100)=453$, and iterating the BBP formula $453$ times, gives a better approximation for $\pi$ and now $J_{100}=7.7472...\cdot10^{-241}$ has $75$ correct digits when comparing with $I_{100}$.

With this $f(n)=\lfloor n(\ln n)^{0.99}\rfloor$ will the truncated BBP formula always produce an approximation of $\pi$ such $J_n$ will always converge, that is $\lim_{n\to\infty}J_n=0$ ? And how close it is from $I_n$
(In the end of this post there is an upper bound for $I_n$. I need an upper bound for $J_n$) ? If the answer is no, there exists a $f(n)$ respecting $(2)$ that will make $J_n$ always converge when $n$ goes to infinity?

**Example: Consider $n=2$**
\begin{align}
I_2&= (12 (-1 + π) - 6 (1 + π) \log(π) + (-1 + π) \log^2(π))/(\log^3(π)) \approx 0.0396.
\end{align}
To find $J_2$ we must find $S_2$:
\begin{align*}
S_{2}=\sum_{k=0}^{f(2)}\left( \frac{4}{16^k(8k+1)}
-   \frac{2}{16^k(8k+4)}
-   \frac{1}{16^k(8k+5)}
-   \frac{1}{16^k(8k+6)}\right)
\end{align*}
where $f(2)=1$, which gives the following approximation for $\pi$:  $S_2=102913/32760.$ Therefore we have,
\begin{align}
J_2&= (12 (-1 + 102913/32760) - 6 (1 + 102913/32760) \log(π) + (-1 + 102913/32760) \log^2(π))/(\log^3(π)) \approx 0.0388.
\end{align}

**More information:**

For some $b>0$,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 x^n b^x \, dx = \int_0^1 x^n e^{\ln(b)\,x} \, dx = \frac{1}{\ln^{n+1}(b)} \int_0^{\ln(b)} x^n e^x \, dx.
\end{align*}
Let's change $x^n$ for a polynomial $P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$,
\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 P_n(x) b^x \, dx = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(b)} \int_0^{\ln(b)} x^k e^x \, dx
\end{align*}
where $\int x^ke^xdx$ has the shape $e^xp_k(x)$ where $p_k(x)$ is a polynomial with degree $k$ and has integer coefficients. The independent coefficient is $k!$.  Integrating from $0$ to $\ln b$ we have $\int_0^{\ln b} x^ke^xdx=e^{\ln b} p_k(\ln b)-e^0p_k(0) = bp_k(\ln b)-k!$.
Take $b=\pi$. Thus,
\begin{align*}
I_n=\int_0^1 P_n(x) \pi^x \, dx &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} \int_0^{\ln(\pi)} x^k e^x \, dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} ( \pi p_k(\ln\pi) - k! ).
\end{align*}
Denote the above integral by $I_n$, where $P_n(x)$ is the following polynomial
\begin{align*}
P_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!}.
\end{align*}
We can integrate by parts $n$ times $I_n$ using the following rule
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b \frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x)g(x)dx=(-1)^n\int_a^b 
f(x)\frac{d^n}{dx^n}g(x)dx
\end{align*}
if $f(a)g(a)=f(b)g(b)=0.$

\begin{align*}
\int_0^1 \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \pi^x dx  &=(-1)^n \int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \pi^xdx\\
&=(-1)^n\int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \pi^x\ln^n\pi dx.
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
|I_n|&=\int_0^1  \frac{(x-x^2)^n}{n!} \pi^x\ln^n\pi dx \\
&\leq\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^1 [max(x-x^2)]^n \pi^x \ln^n\pi dx\\
&=\frac{1}{n!} (1/4)^n \ln^n\pi \int_0^1\pi^xdx\\
&= \frac{1}{n!} (1/4)^n \ln^n\pi \frac{\pi-1}{\ln\pi}.
\end{align*}

Comment: The error is $|I_n - J_n| = |\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{a_k p_k(\ln \pi)}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)} (S_n -  \pi) }| = |S_n - \pi| |\sum_{k=0}^n{\frac{a_k p_k(\ln \pi)}{\ln^{k+1}(\pi)}}|$

Comment: Could you show how derived the formula for $I_n$? It might help bound the error

Comment: @CommandMaster Added more information including an estimation for $I_n$. Maybe this will help create a bound for $J_n$ ?

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455667/is-this-approximation-for-pi-enough-to-make-this-value-converge-and-how-to-f

Answer (score 2):

For
$$J_n=\int_ 0^1 (x-x^2)\,\pi^x\,dx$$ Mathematica gives a nasty regularized hypergeometric function which reduces to
$$J_n=\pi \, \log ^{-n-\frac{1}{2}}(\pi )\, \Gamma (n+1)\, I_{\frac{1}{2} (2
   n+1)}\left(\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}\right)$$

So, naming $K_n$ your integral,
$$K_n=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{\log (\pi )}}\,I_{\frac{1}{2} (2 n+1)}\left(\frac{\log (\pi )}{2}\right)$$ wich is asymptotic to
$$K_n\sim\sqrt \pi \,\,\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}}\,\,\frac{\log^n(\pi)}{(2 n+1)^{n+1} }$$ whose relative error is smaller than $0.10$% if $n >9$ and smaller than $0.01$% if $n >36$